# Does defer runs after function returns?

Tags: go

I've been staring at this code and can't figure out the why of its behavior.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var i int

func example() int {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("defer")
        i = 1
    }()

    fmt.Println("first")
    return i
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(example())
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

At first, the expected output for me is:

```
first
defer
1
1
```

But, as you can see [in the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0mUTWyS6Mnf) the actual output is:

```
first
defer
0
1
```

Is it a deferred anonymous function behavior? [Nope](https://go.dev/play/p/tLjWDErukG1)

So, why is it printing `0`?

Comment: The flow is `first` -> RETURN 0 -> `defer` (set i to 1) -> print return value (0) -> print i (1) - so, essentially, the zero value of `i` is captured on the return before it is updated to 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does defer runs after function returns?

[Certainly](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements).

> So, why is it printing 0?

Because you're returning 0.

`example()` returns an `int` by value.  when `return i` is evaluated, `i`s current value is returned.  After that return is evaluated, the `defer` function executes, changing the value stored at `i` to `1`.  But the `0` value is already the return value.

Go makes it possible to modify the return value of a function, but only if the return value has a name.

For [example, this returns 1](https://go.dev/play/p/AnCtEtlEPhC):

```
func example() (j int) {
   defer func() { j = 1 }()
   return 0
}
```

But in your case, you're not naming your return variable, so you can't modify it in a defer.